# Stop ongoing Start-MpScan?

Tags: windows, powershell-2.0, antivirus

Would you know if there is any way to stop an ongoing Start-MpScan using Powershell? I saw that it may be done using -InformationAction, but for example if I want to check the status of the current scan:

```
Start-MpScan -InformationAction Inquire
```

Or If I want to stop the scan:

```
Start-MpScan -InformationAction Stop
```

They return an error telling that there is an ongoing scan already.

Source: https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dn433288.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can't - the Stop I believe is simply an error action listed on the Start-MPScan - IE when you encounter an error - stop. That's why if no scan is running and you run with the Stop parameter you will start a new scan.